# Некорректно работает поиск по коллекции через rxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Если на вход подать строку 3-20 (это getRegNum()) ничего не отображается, т.е. пустой лист возвращает, хотя такой номер есть в базе, ввожу 495 находит данный док.

```
public Observable gerResultSearch(List<DocRc> rcList, CharSequence text) {
        String finalText = text.toString().toLowerCase();


        Observable<DocRc> getRegNumObservable = Observable.from(rcList).filter(i -> i.getRegNum().toLowerCase().contains(finalText)).distinct(j -> j.getRegNum());
        Observable<DocRc> getRegDateObservable = Observable.from(rcList).filter(i -> i.getRegDate().toLowerCase().contains(finalText)).distinct(j -> j.getRegDate());
        Observable<DocRc> getDescriptObservable = Observable.from(rcList).filter(i -> i.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(finalText)).distinct(j -> j.getDescription());

        Observable<DocRc> getOrganShortName =
                Observable.from(rcList).filter(i -> i.getAuthors().get(0).getContact().getContactOrganizationShortName().toLowerCase().contains(finalText)).distinct(j -> j.
                        getAuthors().get(0).getContact().getContactOrganizationShortName());

        Observable<DocRc> getOffPersonFullname = Observable.from(rcList).filter(i -> i.getResolutions().get(0).getContact().getContactOfficialPersonFullname().toLowerCase().contains(finalText)).distinct(j -> j.getResolutions().get(0).getContact().getContactOfficialPersonFullname());

        Observable<List<DocRc>> compareObservable = Observable.merge(getRegNumObservable, getRegDateObservable, getDescriptObservable, getOrganShortName, getOffPersonFullname).toList();

        return compareObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    }
```